# Converting byte number to grayscale and vica versa

Tags: c++, rgb

I got a number between 0-255 and need to convert it to a RGB grayscale color. And how do I convert a RGB-color to a grayscale value between 0-255?

Comment: How does your number (0-255) represent a color?

Comment: It's from a mask to a picture, the darker the mask pixel is, the more transparent the pixel becomes. It's represented in a RGB(255,255,255)-scale right now but I need to convert it to a value between 0-255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common formula is luminosity = 0.30 * red + 0.59 * green + 0.11 * blue.  Matches the human eye's color perception, doesn't otherwise correct for display device gamma.

Comment: Don't you think that this formula is already applied? Why do you think that the simple averaging is not enough?

Comment: No, RGB always represents device colors.  The non-linearity of the human eye is easy to see (pun intended), fully saturated blue (0, 0, 255) looks much darker than fully saturated green (0, 255, 0).  So dark that it is the background color for the Blue Screen Of Death.

Comment: The intensity of RGB colors are not changing linearly, but that is corrected by the display system. There are not needs to do it again in the software.

Comment: Not on any display I've ever used, (128,128,128) is quite dark.  The original image is however often already gamma corrected so no additional correction is necessary.  Color display is very tricky.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a number `0 <= x <= 255` representing a grayscale value, the corresponding RGB tuple is simply `(x,x,x)`.